# Support solider can't take cover, shoot or heal

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I seem to be encountering a very serious bug and unfortunately it has happened on the alien base assault.

For the past few missions my support sometimes won't take cover, lose the ability to shoot even if he is right next to an enemy and can't heal any friendlies he is within range of. It always goes away when the mission ends and doesn't always reappear.

Unfortunately it happening in the base assault is going to end my Classic/Ironman run because I haven't moved out of the starting room and I've only killed 5 of the 22 aliens.

Does anyone know how to fix this bug?

Comment: I noticed another guy having a similar bug, but it only lasted for a round and it was a sniper. It may or may not be related.

Comment: @kotekzot what do you mean you get to retry the last mission even if you fail on Ironman? I'm on the alien base assault and if I lose all my soldiers the Skyranger will just return to base and I'll be down six soldiers.

Comment: @3ventic I posted this same question on r/xcom and someone there implied that this could actually be a suppression bug. I did have my support suppress a alien who I then killed. It could be that if the alien that is being suppressed is killed the person suppressing bugs out. A suggested fix has been to use a smoke grenade to somehow "phase" my support back into reality. Unfortunately I don't want to burn a smoke grenade since this mission is a bitch.

Comment: Ironman only saves at the beginning of the round.  Try the smoke grenade, if it doesn't work, you can tab out and end process on XCOM.

Comment: @Kexlox ah I understand. Good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is definitely a suppression bug. It seems that if you suppress an alien and then that alien is killed the soldier doing the suppressing will being bugged. They will lose the ability to take cover (and therefore hunker down) as well as shoot or heal friendlies.

HOWEVER if you can heal yourself OR throw a smoke grenade it seems this will snap your soldier back to reality and he will begin functioning normally.

So you should be careful whenever you are doing suppression. Be sure you have another ability like heal or smoke or missiles to fix it if it occurs or just don't attack any aliens once you have suppressed them.